# Generate 1000 HTML pages locally, from a template and just change the title in the head of the page

Tags: html

I have a list of US cities and a template html page. Can I write a script that take  a city name, generates a folder with the same name as the city, and place in that folder the template html page with the title in the head section set to the city name.

I have to make 1000 of these pages and I just want to know if it can be done locally, and if I can automate the process.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have any programming language experience?

Answer (score 0):

it is not too complected to do something like that , but why you would have many files that would make a preformance problems , when I done something like this before I would made one page(your template ) and change the page content based on the city in your case , but if you steel need to make files locally you are using PHP for back-end you can check this topic hope it help : 
 https://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete .

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use something like [Cookie cutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io). Creating the [template](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/first_steps.html) once and running 1000 times using a bash script with different city name each time.

The cookie-cutter project will be structured as follows:

```
$ tree
.
├── {{cookiecutter.city_name}}
│   └── {{cookiecutter.city_name}}.html
└── cookiecutter.json
```

`{{cookiecutter.city_name}}.html` contains the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{cookiecutter.city_name}}</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

`cookiecutter.json` contains the following:

```
{
    "city_name": "Cairo"
}
```

running `$cookiecutter . --no-input city_name=texas` creates the following:

```
└── texas
    └── texas.html
```